# Delete hooks in ndb PolyModel childclass won't execute

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm using `ndb.polymodel.PolyModel` to model different types of social media accounts. After an account has been deleted some cleanup has to be done (depending on the subclass).

I tried implementing a `_pre_delete_hook` on the subclass, but it never gets executed. When adding the exact same hook to its parent class it **does** get executed:

```
class Account(polymodel.PolyModel):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User) 

    @classmethod
    def _pre_delete_hook(cls, key):
        # Works as expected
        pass

class TwitterAccount(Account):
    twitter_profile = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def _pre_delete_hook(cls, key):
        # Never gets called
        pass

t_account = TwitterAccount.get_by_id(1)
t_account.key.delete()
```

Seems strange to me as I would expect the subclass hook to override its parent. Or is this expected behavior?

---

**Solution**:
I missed the fact that a `delete` operation happens on a `Key` (not a model instance). The key itself only knows the name of the topmost class (`Account` in this case).

I ended up defining a custom `_delete_hook` instance method on the subclass. When `_pre_delete_hook` gets called, I fetch the entity and then check if its class has a specific  delete_hook to execute:

```
    # In subclass:
    def _delete_hook(self):
        # Do stuff specific for this subclass
        return

    # In parent class
    @classmethod
    def _pre_delete_hook(cls, key):
        s = key.get()
        if hasattr(s, '_delete_hook'):
            s._delete_hook()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is expected though non-obvious behaviour

When you call `key` delete with a `PolyModel` you are only calling delete on the parent class.

Have a look at the Key you are calling delete on, you will see the Kind is the parent Model. It then looks up the class via the Kind -> class map which will give you an `Account` class. Have a read up on how PolyModel works. It stores all Account sub classes as Account and has an extra property that describes the inheritance heirarchy.  So that a query on Account will return all Account subclasses, but a query on TwitterAccount will only return that subclass.

Calling ndb.delete_multi won't work either.

If you want a specific PolyModel subclass pre delete hook to run, you will have to add a delete method to the subclass, call that, that can then call the subclass _pre_delete_hook (and may be call super).

But that will cause issues if you ever call `key.delete` directly